# Maximum and minimum in a points of discontinuity

Tags: calculus

I want calculate the maximum and minimum of the following function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\Biggl\{
\begin{array}{c}
  \cos x \ \ \ \ \ x\in(0,\pi] \\
  \sin x \ \ \ x\in[-\pi,0] 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
The points $x=-\pi/2$, $x=\pi$ are absolute minimum. Instead, the point $x=-\pi$ is a relative maximum. My question is: what happens in $ x = 0 $? It is not an absolute maximum. It can be a relative maximum?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is your definition of "relative maximum"?

Comment: "the largest value that the function takes at a point either within a given neighborhood"

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: Is the definition on Wikipedia.

Comment: -1 (as usual) for Wikipedia (the full statement there is poorly written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can draw pictures to see this, or just note that when $\pi>x>0$, $cos x>0$, when $-\pi<x<0$, $sin x<0$, and $f(0)=0.$